# R: what does Filter(function handle, data) means in R

Tags: r, filter

The variable getgenes has a column named "GENE". This column has redundant strings.
The purpose is to get the strings that appeared g(g can be 2,3,4...etc) times.

```
x <- Filter(function(elem) length(which(getgenes$GENE == elem)) == g, getgenes$GENE)
```

I searched Filter function in R but cannot find a match that use functon as 1st argument.

What does the Filter means here?

Comment: Sorry for the noise if I'm mistaken but isn't your problem a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Aren't you looking for `table(GENE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help page, "Filter extracts the elements of a vector for which a predicate (logical) function gives true." If you look at the source, you can see that

```r
x <- Filter(function(elem) length(which(getgenes$GENE == elem)) == g, getgenes$GENE)
```

is equivalent to:

```r
x <- getgenes$GENE[which(as.logical(unlist(lapply(getgenes$GENE,
                                                  function(elem) length(which(getgenes$GENE == elem)) == g))))]
```

However, this seems a roundabout way of arriving at the answer. Under some mild assumptions about the structure of getgenes and g, I believe the expression can be simplified to:

```r
x <- getgenes$GENE[getgenes$GENE %in% names(which(table(getgenes$GENE) == g))]
```

if you are willing to forgo duplicates, it can be simplified even further.